# ошибка в foreach

Tags: php, sql

Здравствуйте тут на форуме дали подсказку, но она с ошибкой.
Суть скрипта — чтобы он заносил каждую запись в новую строку.

Ошибка:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'list' (T_LIST) in

на этой строке:

```
foreach($success_list as list($id,$catalog,$filename,$catalog_small,$filename_small)){

 $stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO images_big(id, catalog, filename, catalog_small, filename_small) 
    VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)");
list($id,$catalog,$filename,$catalog_small,$filename_small)=$success_list[0];
$stmt->bindParam(1,$id,PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(2,$catalog,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(3,$filename,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(4,$catalog_small,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(5,$filename_small,PDO::PARAM_STR);
foreach($success_list as list($id,$catalog,$filename,$catalog_small,$filename_small)){
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Comment: list  у Вас это что? Функция?

Comment: да это функция у меня

Comment: Вам нужно обновить вашу версию php скорее всего. У вас какая? На 7й версии у меня этот код работает. Ну если не учитывать недостающей в конце закрывающей }

Answer (score 2):

Синтаксис [`foreach .. as list()`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) был добавлен в музейной PHP 5.5.0. Проверьте, что вы используете PHP версии хотя бы 5.5.х.

Довольно странная мысль обходить весь `$success_list`, но записывать в БД `count($success_list)` идентичных копий первого элемента.

Comment: поставил php7 Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'id' cannot be null in /home/a0031620/domains/yourdosug.ru/public_html/kiev/registration/1/upload.php:83
Stack trace:
#0 /home/a0031620/domains/yourdosug.ru/public_html/kiev/registration/1/upload.php(83): PDOStatement-&gt;execute()
#1 {main}
  thrown in <b>/home/a0031620/domains/yourdosug.ru/public_html/kiev/registration/1/upload.php</b> on line <b>83</b><br />

Comment: /home/a0031620/domains/yourdosug.ru/public_html/kiev/registr‌​ation/1/upload.php заказ девушек в Киеве онлайн?) Интересный проект у Вас.
По теме, исключение вылазиет на уровне вашей БД и говоричт колонка ID не может быть пустой.

Comment: $stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO images_big(id, catalog, filename, catalog_small, filename_small) 
    VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)");
list($id,$catalog,$filename,$catalog_small,$filename_small)=$success_list[0];
$stmt->bindParam(1,$_GET['id'],PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(2,$catalog,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(3,$filename,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(4,$catalog_small,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(5,$filename_small,PDO::PARAM_STR);
foreach($success_list as list($_GET['id'],$catalog,$filename,$catalog_small,$filename_small)){
    $stmt->execute();
} так сделал

Comment: Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'id' cannot be null in /home/a0031620/domains/yourdosug.ru/public_html/kiev/registration/1/upload.php:83
Stack trace:
#0 /home/a0031620/domains/yourdosug.ru/public_html/kiev/registration/1/upload.php(83): PDOStatement-&gt;execute()
#1 {main}
  thrown in <b>/home/a0031620/domains/yourdosug.ru/public_html/kiev/registration/1/upload.php</b> on line <b>83</b><br />

Comment: @Koly, добавь auto_increment  к полю id в БД или не передавай туда NULL или лучше создать новый вопрос и там подробно описать проблему. На изначальную проблему в этом вопросе ответ был вроде дан.